# Simple Javascript Image Rotation Not Properly Looping

Tags: javascript, rotation

This is a simple rotation script that is not working. It has four alerts: currentImage, 1, 2, and 3. In FF it goes through four alerts and stops. In Chrome, it goes through five. The image only changes once in both browsers.

```
function rotateImages(currentImage, id) {
  var dir = "/images/";
  var a = new Array("coolspider1.jpg", "coolspider2.jpg", "coolspider3.jpg");

  var b = document.getElementById(id);

  if(currentImage >= a.length){
    currentImage=0;}

//loop stops here in ff

alert(a[currentImage]);

//loop stops here in chrome

b.src = dir + a[currentImage];
alert(1);

currentImage++;
alert(2);

rotator = window.setTimeout("rotateImages(" + currentImage + "," + id + ")",500);
alert(3);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot of issues here:

- You are accessing the DOM too much with getElementById each time. Instead pass the element.
- You are creating the same array each time. `var a = new Array(...)` can be created once.
- You are never assigning to `currentImage`
- You are using setTimeout weirdly, instead of a simple loop, `for(i;etc..) setTimeout(func, 500 + i*500, params...)`
- You are using alert for something... not sure

Replace:

```
window.setTimeout("rotateImages(" + currentImage + "," + id + ")",500);
```

with:

```
window.setTimeout(rotateImages,500, currentImage, id);
```

[setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setTimeout) takes optional parameters of the... well, parameters.